# Which is the best programming language to write a web bot?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, robots.txt, bots

I want know which programming language provides good number of libraries to program a web bot?
Something like crawling a web page for data. Say I want fetch weather for weather.yahoo.com website.

Also will the answer be same for a AI desktop bot?

Comment: Anything which comes with comfortable libraries really. I'd have a look at Python or Java if I were you. Depending on how much interaction and/or performance you require for your AI bot, I would look at functional languages (OCaml, Haskell, F#) for that kind of task.

Comment: I don't have any requirement. But lets say too much interaction and high performance needed.

Comment: One you know well and has decent network primitives?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is how you could do it in Python:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
soup=BeautifulSoup(urlopen("http://weather.yahoo.com/").read())
for x in soup.find(attrs={"id":"myLocContainer"}).findAll("li"):
  print x.a["title"], x.em.contents
```

Prints:

Full forecast for Chicago, Illinois, United States (Haze) [u'35...47 °F']
Full forecast for London, Greater London, England (Light Rain) [u'43...45 °F']
Full forecast for New York, New York, United States (Partly Cloudy) [u'42...62 °F']
Full forecast for San Francisco, California, United States (Partly Cloudy) [u'51...70 °F']

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it is **the best**, but *Python* is definitely pretty good and simple for that.

Answer (score 1):

Another good python library for screen scraping and web crawling is [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/).